# Android app stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-wifi

I wrote a program for android which connects to internet.

I got the following error:

```
The application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again..
```

What's the problem?

Log cat in Eclipse is as follows:

```
09-02 12:43:42.421: W/dalvikvm(12362): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.networkusage/com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.networkusage-1.apk]
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.networkusage-1.apk]
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
09-02 12:43:42.437: E/AndroidRuntime(12362):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Rather than showing the logcat please show the code you have tried.

Comment: The problem according to LogCat is this: ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity

Comment: Have you defined the activity in your manifest xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Found that my package name is:

com.example.android.networkusage

and on the manifest is as:

android:name="com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity"

so changed the manifest to:

android:name="com.example.android.networkusage.NetworkActivity"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity` class is missing.

If it is declared in an external library, add that **jar file** to the "**libs**" folder and **add it to the build path** and then **build your project again**.

Don't forget to **clean** it too!